# Installing Chef-Server on Fedora 18

Tags: fedora, chef

I am trying to install chef-server on a Fedora 18 aws small instance. The first steps that I have done are the following:

```
yum update
rpm -Uvh http://rbel.frameos.org/rbel6
```

With the intention of bring the Fedora 18 instance up to the latest updates and installing the repo from which I will install the chef-server from.

The next step I did was the following:

```
yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="rbel6" install rubygem-chef-server
```

Which causes me the following problem which I will be needing your assistance in. Note that I am purposely disabling the other repos because it would appear that some of the packages that are outdated versions that don't seem to be available from the fedora repo.

```
Error: Package: rubygem-chef-server-0.10.6-1.el6.noarch (rbel6)
       Requires: java-1.6.0-openjdk
Error: Package: couchdb-0.11.2-2.el6.x86_64 (rbel6)
       Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: rubygem-chef-server-0.10.6-1.el6.noarch (rbel6)
       Requires: libxml2-devel
Error: Package: rubygem-chef-server-0.10.6-1.el6.noarch (rbel6)
       Requires: ntp
Error: Package: ruby-libs-1.8.7.352-4.el6.x86_64 (rbel6)
       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: erlang-R12B-5.10.el6.x86_64 (rbel6)
       Requires: tk
Error: Package: couchdb-0.11.2-2.el6.x86_64 (rbel6)
       Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: rubygem-chef-server-0.10.6-1.el6.noarch (rbel6)
       Requires: java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
Error: Package: ruby-libs-1.8.7.352-4.el6.x86_64 (rbel6)
       Requires: libgdbm.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: couchdb-0.11.2-2.el6.x86_64 (rbel6)
       Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: erlang-R12B-5.10.el6.x86_64 (rbel6)
       Requires: libodbc.so.2()(64bit)
```

After dealing with the dependencies that I could easily resolve:

```
yum install ntp
yum install tx
yum install libxml2-devel
```

After running the command : yum install 'libodbc.so.2' and successfully installing the package :

```
yum install 'libodbc.so.2'
Package unixODBC-2.3.1-2.fc18.i686 already installed and latest version
```

I am still getting the error message:

```
Error: Package: erlang-R12B-5.10.el6.x86_64 (rbel6)
       Requires: libodbc.so.2()(64bit)
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error and I would appreciate any help in explaining the issue to me and helping me resolve it.

The other packages were not in the fedora repo so I googled for the rpms, downloaded them using wget, and installed them using yum install (if there is a better way to do this please tell me because it can be a pain, esp when there may be more dependencies):

```
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/releases/18/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/u/unixODBC-2.3.1-2.fc18.i686.rpm
yum install unixODBC-2.3.1-2.fc18.i686.rpm
wget ftp://ftp.muug.mb.ca/mirror/fedora/linux/updates/16/x86_64/java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel-1.6.0.0-71.1.11.6.fc16.x86_64.rpm
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-71.1.11.6.fc16.x86_64.rpm
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel-1.6.0.0-71.1.11.6.fc16.x86_64.rpm
```

Which leaves me wit this error message after doing all of the above:

```
Error: Package: erlang-R12B-5.10.el6.x86_64 (rbel6)
       Requires: libodbc.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: ruby-libs-1.8.7.352-4.el6.x86_64 (rbel6)
       Requires: libgdbm.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: ruby-libs-1.8.7.352-4.el6.x86_64 (rbel6)
       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
```

I am not sure what I can do about libgdbm since it appears to a core package and is already installed so not sure what it isn't being detected and I haven't tried installing libdb-4.7.so as I want to get the first two issues resolved. Any advice on how I should proceed from here?

P.S. I apologize for the level of details here. I was hoping that someone would look at what I am doing and tell me that there is a better way of doing this since I just learned how to do these kinds of things ad hoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume you those packages are looking for 64Bit version of that lib.

So,

```
'sudo yum search unixODBC'
```

comes up with this package "unixODBC-2.3.1-2.fc18.x86_64.rpm"